# Android Studio No address associated with hostname using Inet Address

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, inetaddress

I'm having a problem with my ip lookup program in Java I've imported Inet Adress and implementd the async task and used the permission on the manifest but still shows the same problem.
The Error: **Unable to resolve host "[Ljava.lang.String;@f1679a5": No address associated with hostname**
I've been seaching all over the internet and some of them say that It's the emulator problem BUT I can access internet on my device I've done everything they've recommended but still no solutions.

Here is the code Part:

```
  EditText hostnumber;
TextView output;
Button submit;
ImageView back;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lookup);
    back = findViewById(R.id.backlearn);

    hostnumber = findViewById(R.id.hostnumber);
    output = findViewById(R.id.outputDecimal);
    submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Lookup.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") AsyncTask<String, Void, connection.Result<InetAddress>> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, connection.Result<InetAddress>>() {
                // NOTE: this method runs in a background thread, you cannot access the View from here
                @Override
                protected connection.Result<InetAddress> doInBackground(String... hostnumber) {
                    connection.Result<InetAddress> result;
                    try {
                        result = new connection.Result.Success(InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(hostnumber)));
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        result = new connection.Result.Failure(e);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        result = new connection.Result.Failure(e);
                    }

                    return result;
                }


                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(connection.Result<InetAddress> result) {
                    if (result instanceof connection.Result.Success) {
                        output.setText((CharSequence) ((connection.Result.Success<InetAddress>) result).data);
                    } else if (result instanceof connection.Result.Failure) {
                       Throwable error = ((connection.Result.Failure<InetAddress>) result).error;
                        Toast.makeText(Lookup.this,"Please Check The Address!: " +error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            };

            task.execute(hostnumber.toString());
        };
    })
    ;}

}
class connection extends Activity {
    static class Result<T> {
        static class Success<T> extends Result<T> {
            public T data;
            public Success(T data) {
                this.data = data;
            }
        }
        static class Failure<T> extends Result<T> {
            public Throwable error;
            public Failure(Throwable error) {
                this.error = error;
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong, cause I believe so? or some emulator or debug problem from android studio part. if you have any solutions for this I'd appreciate it. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did u test it on real phone?

Comment: @navylover I just ran it on a real device and the same problem